# Hide Adsense blocks while page loads

Tags: google-adsense

While my page loads, I hide everything (opacity: 0) on it and just show a progressbar until it's finished. Then I show everything (opacity: 1). It is ok to hide the Google Adsense blocks too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loading screen could be classed as interfering with normal site navigation since most websites you are able to navigate even when page elements are **not** completely loaded.

> [SOURCE](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295#Placing_Google_ads_on_a_website_with_pop-ups)
>
> Additionally, sites with Google AdSense may not be loaded by any
>   software that triggers pop-ups, modifies browser settings, redirects
>   users to unwanted websites, or **otherwise interferes with normal site**
>   **navigation**

You should however content Google to confirm...